# Strange HTML and CSS behavior

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome

One of my clients has been encountering this issue when she goes onto the app. I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to get it to show normally? Im not sure if this is a code issue or her computer.

[Everything is getting bunched together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imItA.png)

Edit: I did not provide the code because it is very lengthy and I feel like there could be another answer that isn't linked to my code since it is only happening to that computer.

Comment: You are about to get a bunch of down votes for not supplying the code or link to your project. 

Fair warning *i wont but others will*

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a lot to go off of this. It could be as simple as changing the width of the input tag which would take almost no time to fix. If you're using bootstrap or some other framework maybe a class name is messed up somewhere in the html. It would be a lot easier to pinpoint what exactly the problem is if there were code to go along with it. Also there could be no problem with the code and could just simply be her machine, but there is still no way to figure that out without looking over it.

Comment: I understand. I was hoping for someone that might have came across the same issue some time. Its interesting that it is only happening to that computer so I was hoping for some diagnosis and other opinions.